# Object.entries alternative transforming array of object into strings

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I tried to print `"person[0].name: a"` and `"person[1].name: b"` and so on, based on this person array of object:

I used object entries twice, any other way I can make the loop more efficient?

```js
const person = [{
  name: 'a',
}, {
  name: 'b'
}]

Object.entries(person).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  Object.entries(value).forEach(([key2, value2]) => {
    console.log(`person[${key}].${key2}`, ':', value2)
  })
})
```

Comment: Is your aim to just print the values at the name key or transform your array into an array of names (eg: `['a', 'b']`)?

Comment: do you have nested objects/arrays as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need the first call. `person` is already an Array.

```js
const person = [{
  name: 'a',
}, {
  name: 'b'
}]


person.forEach((value, key) => {
  Object.entries(value).forEach(([key2, value2]) => {
    console.log(`person[${key}].${key2}`, ':', value2)
  })
})
```

Just in case `forEach` is for side effects. If you want to create another array with transformed values you better use `map`/`flatMap` instead.

```js
const person = [{
  name: 'a',
}, {
  name: 'b'
}]


const transformed = person.flatMap((value, key) => {
  return Object.entries(value).map(([key2, value2]) => `person[${key}].${key2}:${value2}`)
})

console.log(transformed)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach and hand over the parent path.

```js
const
    show = (object, parent) => {
        const wrap = Array.isArray(object) ? v => `[${v}]` : v => `.${v}`;
        Object.entries(object).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (v && typeof v === 'object') show(v, parent + wrap(k));
            else console.log(parent + wrap(k), v);
        });
    },
    person = [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }];

show(person, 'person');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this, with only one forEach() loop

```js
const person = [{
    name: 'a',
  },{
      name: 'b'
  }];
  
  
person.forEach((el,i) => {
        let prop = Object.keys(el).toString();
        
        console.log(`person[${i}].${prop}`, ':', el[prop])  
});
```